# Help me solve this permissions issue with IIS

Tags: iis, asp-classic, permissions

I'm getting a login challenge for any asp script residing in a specific virtual directory in IIS.

The virtual directory in question, called "videos" in IIS, is pointed at a mapped network drive on my web server (http://192.168.47.13:8367/videos).

The mapped network drive on my web server points to a folder on a remote server (\\192.168.47.112\SVC) within my intranet.

I'm not sure if that is enough information to help you help me or not but if you need anything else answered please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

When configuring a virtual directory to use "A share located on another computer", you can provide the credentials to use to connect to that particular network share using the "Connect As..." button. If this hasn't been configured and there is limited access to the share you will run into problems.